# Java - Converting to Lambda with a boolean to return

Tags: java, lambda

I haven't used much of Lambda and I have the following method that I'd like to rewrite as Lambda, so it still maintains the functionality, but in a more compact way. The method gets a map out of a map by an id. Then looks for 2 conditions in the map to return true. My current issue is that I'm not finding a proper syntax to do a "return true;" statement from my Lambda. That was part #1. Part #2 question is about using nested maps. The nested map represent static data from a small csv file - under 100 rows. The inner map contains between 1 to 3 records. Is there a better way storing this in memory besides using a nested map? Would love to have some help here.
Old function as follows:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> availability;

public boolean hasAvailability(int quantity, String currentLocation, Product product) {
    Map<String, Integer> m = this.availability.get(product.getProductId());
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(currentLocation) && entry.getValue().intValue() > quantity)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `anyMatch` on a `stream` of the `entrySet`, also you don't need to call `toString()` on a `String`. Like,

```
public boolean hasAvailability(int quantity, String currentLocation, Product product) {
    Map<String, Integer> m = this.availability.get(product.getProductId());
    return m.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(
            entry -> entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(currentLocation) &&
            entry.getValue().intValue() > quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.  Just stream the entrySet and return true or false if the entry is located.

```
public boolean hasAvailability(int quantity, String currentLocation, Product product) {
    Map<String, Integer> m = this.availability.get(product.getProductId());
    return m.entrySet().stream()
          .anyMatch(entry->entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(currentLocation) &&
                    entry.getValue() > quantity);
    
}
```

Note that you could turn the above into a `lambda` but you would need to declare a functional interface that accepted three paramaters and returned a boolean.  I don't believe that is what you really want or should do.  The above approach still streamlines the requirement a bit.